# Error: Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy does not support the "cross-origin" policy

Tags: reactjs

Following errors shows while i am working on react project:

```
`throw new Error
(`Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy does not support the 
${JSON.stringify(policy)} policy`)
                      ^

Error: Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy does not support the "cross-origin" policy`
```

I have searched for Embedder Policy but didn't get the solution.
I don't know what to do with it.

Here is full code:

These are import statements where other js files are extra pages files to be imported

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import cors from 'cors'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import helmet from 'helmet'
import morgan from 'morgan'
import clientRoutes from './routes/client.js'
import generalRoutes from './routes/general.js'
import managementRoutes from './routes/management.js'
import salesRoutes from './routes/sales.js'
```

```
//configuration
dotenv.config()
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(helmet())
app.use(helmet.crossOriginEmbedderPolicy({policy:"cross-origin"}))
app.use(morgan("common"))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(cors())

//routes
app.use("/client",clientRoutes);
app.use("/general",generalRoutes);
app.use("/management",managementRoutes);
app.use("/sales",salesRoutes);

//mongodb setup
const PORT=process.env.PROT || 9000;
mongoose
.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTpology:true,
})
.then(()=>{
    app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log(`Server Port:${PORT}`));
})
.catch((error)=>console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```